# React is not rendering my javascript file

Tags: reactjs

I am copying exact code as tutorial. But my code is not rendering.

```
*import React from "react";
 import ReactDom from "react-dom";
 const element = <h1>Hello world</h1>;
 ReactDom.render(element, document.getElementById("root"));
 *
```

Anyone please help. I am trying to learn react from scratch.

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you are trying, what you are seeing, and the details around how you are attempting to run this. With this alone it is impossible to tell what problem you are facing.

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? How are you trying to make react render? And are you seeing an error?

Comment: `import ReactDOM from "react-dom";`

Comment: No error while compiling but element is not printing in browser.

Comment: Thanks guys it was not working on Internet Explorer.I tried it on chrome it worked fine !!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

const Element = () => <h1>Hello world</h1>;
ReactDom.render(<Element/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Otherwise, there is something set up elsewhere in your project

Comment: SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number       This error when is console.log(element)       in console after inspecting page.